# turn off event listener after triggered once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that triggers a popover box which offers a free download.  It triggers when a user's mouse leaves the page (obviously not for mobile - I already have a working solution for that).  In my script I set a cookie to deactivate the script for 30 minutes, and that part works; if I refresh the page the popover doesn't show again.

The problem is that if someone closes the popover box, and haven't refreshed the page (or navigated to another page on the site), the popover occurs every time the mouse moves out of the page.

I am using a function that sets the event, but I can't make it only fire once.
(The Wordpress site I am working on is using jquery ver=1.10.2.)

My Javascript:

```js
if (document.cookie.indexOf('somecookiename') != -1) {
  function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
      obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
      obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
  }
};
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf('somecookiename') == -1) {
    //var thirtyminutes = 1000*60*30;
    var thirtyminutes = 1000 * 60;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + thirtyminutes);
    document.cookie = "somecookiename;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();

    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
      e = e ? e : window.event;
      var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
      if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
        document.getElementById("preview-download").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("back-shader").style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }
});

function showhide(id) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if (obj.style.display == "none") {
      obj.style.display = "";
    } else {
      obj.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

The HTML:

```html
<div id="back-shader" class="popover2">
  <div id="preview-download" class="popover2">
    <h4>BEFORE YOU GO:</h4>
    <h5>Download A Free Preview....</h5>
    <a href="http://website.com/document.pdf" id="preview-pdf">Download Now</a>
    <a href="#" id="closer" onclick="showhide('back-shader'); return(false);"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
#back-shader,
#preview-download {
  display: none;
}
```

It may be something simple, but I am not a javascript expert.  Your help, as always, is appreciated.

Comment: Function declarations are not allowed inside conditionals, and produce different results on different browsers.

Comment: Re: `showhide()`, you know there's `$(element).toggle()`?

Comment: just use the `.off` method after it was shown to the user to cancel the event listener?

Comment: @Bjorn - Yes, I was in fact planning to use .toggle(), but it didn't work for me on this code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way is removing the event listener using [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener):

```
document.addEventListener("mouseout", function handler(e) {
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, handler);
    /* whatever */
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function handler(e) {
  e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, handler);
  alert('Only once');
});
```

```html
Click somewhere
```

Comment: i agree this is the way to go, just be aware you need to name the function something. it won't work if you declare an anonymous handler like: `element.addEventListener('click', function(){})`

Comment: Hi Oriol, how is it that we can have a callback of handler in the definition of handler() itself? I don't understand why this is possible because it seems circular to me!

Answer (score 4):

The javascript version of turning off listener after one invoke is this:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",callback,{
        // This will invoke the event once and de-register it afterward
        once: true
});
```

Answer (score 3):

the simplest solution if you use jQuery - use `.one()` instead of `.on()` this equals to triggering `.off()` in on
http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, might as well just use `Off()`

The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`. Here's the documentation: 
http://api.jquery.com/off/