# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Jquery Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic unordered list  in my HTML. When I load the file some list items are added in .
The format of my  is like this when a page is loaded.

```
<ul class="ui-front">
<li><div>1</div></li>
<li><div>2</div></li>
<li><div>3</div></li>
<li><div>4</div></li>
</ul>
```

Now I am running a function when the page loads the first child of list item get removed and I am trying to add my custom HTML in the list item. This is my code for it

```
$('.ui-front').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'li', function(e) {
    var arjuna="e.target.firstElementChild.innerHTML";
    e.target.removeChild(e.target.childNodes[0]);


    $(e.target).append('<hr style="margin-top:7px;margin-bottom:7px">');
});
```

According to this function when a new list item is inserted then this method calls. But this gives me an error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

When I remove the function `.append`. Everything works fine means elements get remove but whenever I add `.append` it gives me error. Any kind of help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that error because your event is firing on :

`$('.ui-front').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'li', function(e)`

Once you append a new node to the DOM, it will keep re-firing your event. This is why it's exceeding the call stack.

"The DOMNodeInserted event is similar to the DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument event, but it occurs when a node is added to an element."

Comment: Can u give me a solution actually I m trying to replace the html of list item with my html

Comment: If you are just trying to adjust styling, then assign classes with CSS and depending on how you want your changes made, add/remove the classes for dynamic styling with your event listener. You don't need to append nodes to the DOM to accomplish design changes.

Comment: let me tell u whole story i have an input type search when i change the search input value the suggestion list loaded .. I am just trying to change design of that suggestion list

Answer (score 2):

`$(e.target).append` is triggering a `DOMNodeInserted` event. It's an infinite loop.

Comment: Can u give me a solution actually I m trying to replace the html of list item with my html

Comment: I don't know enough about your end goal to thoroughly help, but I would look in to CSS to make what appears to be borders/underlines. There are first element selectors, last element selectors, and borders that I think could be composed to get what you're after.

Comment: let me tell u whole story i have an input type search when i change the search input value the suggestion list loaded .. I am just trying to change design of that suggestion list

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` I used this library

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your issue being clear now from the other answers, a possible solution for your use case is to remove the event listener after first execution (if indeed you only want the event handler to execute once). Something like:

```
$('.ui-front').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'li', function(e) {
    var arjuna="e.target.firstElementChild.innerHTML";
    e.target.removeChild(e.target.childNodes[0]);

    //disables the event handler after first execution
    $('.ui-front').off('DOMNodeInserted');

    //now this won't fire the event anymore :)
    $(e.target).append('<hr style="margin-top:7px;margin-bottom:7px">');
});
```

More info in [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617719/turn-off-event-listener-after-triggered-once)

**Edit:** I'm not exactly sure about your desired output, but if all you are doing is inserting a horizontal line below below the target `<li>`, then this is definitely doable using CSS only (think `border-bottom`, `text-decoration: underline`, or similar).

Comment: no this is not my exactly output... but i tried your it didn't  work as well